# Generate cURL output from Moya request?

Tags: ios, alamofire, moya

I'm using [Moya](https://github.com/Moya/Moya) and need to print the cURL for a network request.

> Usually, in Alamofire 4, I would do something like this:

```
let req = Alamofire.request(someURLRequestConvertible)
debugPrint(req) // will print cURL
```

> My call site for Moya looks like this:

```
MyMoyaProvider.request(MyEndPoints.login(params)) { (result) in }
```

I've checked out the documentation for Moya, but I can't seem to get the results I'm looking for. I enabled the `NetworkLoggingPlugin` but still unsure how to print `cURL` for certain requests. Can someone help me find the proper way to print the Moya `request`'s `cURL` to console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you initialize your `NetworkLoggerPlugin`, its `cURL` flag is set to `false` by default. Initializing it like `NetworkLoggerPlugin(cURL: true)`, `willSendRequest` should print the `cURL`.

As per [@BasThomas](https://github.com/BasThomas) on GitHub: https://github.com/Moya/Moya/issues/1037#event-1027530791

Answer (score 1):

For Moya 14.0.*

```swift
static fileprivate let provider = MoyaProvider<ApiService>(endpointClosure: { (target: ApiService) -> Endpoint in
    let defaultEndpoint = MoyaProvider.defaultEndpointMapping(for: target)
    switch target {
    default:
        let httpHeaderFields = ["Content-Type" : "application/json"]
        return defaultEndpoint.adding(newHTTPHeaderFields: httpHeaderFields)
    }
}, plugins: [
    NetworkLoggerPlugin(configuration: .init(formatter: .init(), output: { (target, array) in
        if let log = array.first {
            print(log)
        }
    }, logOptions: .formatRequestAscURL))
])
```